# Extract chalk lines from image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

I would like to extract chalk lines on grass from an image. An example is below. Here is what I've tried so far:

- Convert the image to HSV then applying a hue filter based on the colour of the grass. This sort of works however, it's not very robust. Once I get it working for one image, the next doesn't seem to have the same hue.
- Apply niblack thresholding to a grey scale version of the image then apply some image morphologies to filter out the noise. Again this seems to be situational, some images work, but others don't.

Are these approaches in the right direction? Is there a way to "standardize" the hue so that I could apply the hue filter? I've tried searching for this online, but as soon as you use the work "line" the vast majority of results are for thin line extraction on a black background.

My next though is to make an "adaptive" hue threshold. The grass covers the majority of the image. First find a hue range that covers, say 90%, of the values then filter based on that range instead of a fixed one.

[image: Chalk and grass]

**Update:**

The "adaptive" threshold seemed to have worked will for this image. But it doesn't work as well when there is more noise in the image. The range basically covers all hue values.

Here is the code I put together to calculate the hue range to filter out:

```
img = imread('image.jpg');
hsv = rgb2hsv(img);
h = hsv(:,:,1);
[counts, edges] = histcounts(h,360);
[maxCount, maxInd] = max(counts);

total = sum(counts);
rng = [maxInd, maxInd];
while (sum(counts(rng(1):rng(2)))/total) < 0.89
    rng(1) = rng(1) - 1;
    if(rng(1) < 1)
        rng(1) = 360;
    end
    rng(2) = rng(2) + 1;
    if(rng(2) > 360)
        rng(1) = 1;
    end
end
```

With the above image I get this result (which is quite good I might add):

[image: result of adaptive threshold]

But with a more noisy image (more shade, brown patches, etc.) I get the range spans almost 0 to 360. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0wz9.jpg) is an example where the above algorithm doesn't work.